# Creating a static method

Tags: static

Here's my code.

```
public static String hBlanks(String a, String b){

    StringBuilder blanks = new StringBuilder();

    int j;
    for(int x = 0; x < a.length(); x++){
      blanks.append('-');
    }
    System.out.println(blanks);
    String strBlanks = blanks.toString();

    for(int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++){
      j = 0;
      while(j < b.length()){
        boolean check = a.contains(b.charAt(j));
```

//I keep getting an error on the boolean check = a.contains(b.charAt(j)); line. It says: "contains(java.lang.CharSequence) in java.lang.String cannot be applied to (char)"

```
        if(check == true){
          strBlanks = blanks.replace('-', "" + a.charAt(i));
```

//And I get another error at the str = strBlanks.replace('-', "" + a.charAt(i)); line. That one says "cannot find symbol
symbol  : method replace(char,java.lang.String)
location: class java.lang.String"

```
        }else{
          j++;
        }
      }
     return strBlanks;
    }
}
```

Comment: strBlanks = strBlanks.replace('-', "" + a.charAt(i));

Comment: This is the error I'm getting for that line: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method replace(char,java.lang.String)
location: class java.lang.String

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of your compilation issues, 
Change `strBlanks.replace('-', "" + a.charAt(i));` to

```
strBlanks.replace('-', a.charAt(1));
```

Also change `a.contains(b.charAt(j));` to

```
a.contains("" + b.charAt(1));
```

Answer (score 0):

How about just one line, instead of all that code:

```
public static String wordBlanks(String a, CharSequence b){
    return a.replaceAll("[^" + b + "]", "-");
}
```

This works by creating a regex that matches every character *not* in `b` and using that to replace ever occurrence in `a` with a dash.